# I have most of the password for my 7z archive. How can I crack it?

Tags: 7-zip, password-recovery

I know most of my password. I think I've only got some capitalization and/or some character inversions in certain spots. What is the fastest way to try all combinations?

If that still doesn't work what is the best way to start searching the space around my supposed password?

Answer (score 1):

Fastest way is to automate the task, i.e., scripting.

This is where bash/shell scripting comes in. Of course this requires knowledge in that field.

Or, you could try my [app](http://shouravbr.com/pickerPY) inspired from such situation.

Comment: Fastest way is to write down a password hint or not forget the password.

Comment: Aye, forgot that one.

Comment: @Chiyou To be fair, for this question it's too late for that. Also, I wouldn't agree that writing down a password hint is a good idea.

Comment: @sblair: What do you mean is fair? It's a f. jungle. Also, I wouldn't download anything from the internet without proof or open source code!?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you like php you you can download this package: http://pear.php.net/package/Math_Combinatorics and feed it with you uncomplete string and figure out how many combinations you missed. I don't have any experience with this library but it seems to solve a lot of headache for some people.